# Camel spring dynamic initializing depending on message

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have camel route builder that only checks the type of request:

```
    public void configure() throws Exception {
               from(IN_ENDPOINT)
               .choice()
                  .when(isReadReq())
                    .to(readRouteBuilder)
                  .when(isWriteReq())
                    .to(writeRouteBuilder);
```

and then passes message further to route builders where actual work is done.
readRouteBuilder looks like:

```
ReadRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    private final Processor exceptionProcessor;
    private final Processor responseProcessor;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
   from(endpoint)
   .process(exceptionProcessor)
   .process(responseProcessor);
}
```

these builders are initialized by spring and my use different implementations od processors depending on client id in the message. There can be a lot of clientIds.
My question is how to make camel (or spring) aware that I want to use specific spring bean when dealing with client A and other for client B and so forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that your different clients require different implementations. 
So you must be getting the clientId to identify them. Then set it in exchange object as soon as you get the call. i.e

```
 public void configure() throws Exception {
               from(IN_ENDPOINT).process(exchange -> {
                // Get the clientId from incoming msg and set it in exchange
                 exchange.setProperty("CLIENT_ID" , getClient()) 
                })
               .choice()
                  .when(isReadReq())
                    .to(readRouteBuilder)
                  .when(isWriteReq())
                    .to(writeRouteBuilder);
```

Now, You have the clientId in exchange object which can be used anywhere down the route to identify your client. Now, to call different implementation you can do this:

```
 ReadRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
        private final Processor exceptionProcessor;
        private final Processor responseProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       from(endpoint)
           // you can configure exception processor in OnException clause
           .onException(Exception.class).process(exceptionProcessor)
           .end()
           .when(matches("CLIENT_A")).process("processorForClientA")
           .when(matches("CLIENT_B")).process("processorForClientB")
           .when(matches("CLIENT_C")).process("processorForClientC")
           .when(matches("CLIENT_D")).process("processorForClientD")
           // And so forth
           .otherwise().process(defaultProcessor)
           .process(responseProcessor);
           }

       protected Predicate matches( String clientId) {
            return 
             exchangeProperty("CLIENT_ID").isEqualToIgnoreCase(clientId);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I meant was processorForClientA, processorForClientB, etc. point to the same class, only spring injects different beans.